# what sql query i should use to if perform same operation which have same value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table_AGE with 4 columns OrgID, EmpID, Name, Salary. I want to display OrgID values whose EmpID values have salary more than 1000.
so if any of EmpID does not satisfy condition then OrgID value should not be printed. To display OrgID, all respective EmpID should meet salary criteria.

```
|OrgID|EmpID|Name|Salary|
|-----|-----|----|------| 
|1    |1    |Sam |800   |
|1    |2    |Gel |1200  |
|2    |1    |Moy |1100  |
|2    |2    |Gar |1300  |
|1     |3    |Joy |2000  |
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Don't spam the tags. In addition, `where Day = 1` makes no sense since there is no such column in your table.

Comment: I want to display ID1 values whose ID2 values have salary more than 1000.

Comment: If any of ID2 doesn't satisfy salary condition, then ID1 should not be printed.

Comment: @SMor Can you please help

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display ID1 values whose ID2 values have salary more than 1000. so if any of ID2 does not satisfy condition then ID1 value should not print.

You can use aggregation:

```
select id1
from t
group by id1
having min(salary) > 1000;
```

Comment: ID1 value should be printed for those ID2 only who satisfy salary condition.
Please help.

Comment: @Adityasharma . . . That is what this does.

Comment: It is displaying ID1 value if any of ID2 satisfy salary condition but i want If any of ID2 doesn't satisfy salary condition, then ID1 should not be printed.

Comment: @Adityasharma . . . No.  The `MIN()` insists that the *smallest* value is at least 100.

Comment: To clear your confusion, i updated column name in questions with ID1 as OrgID (which will be Organization ID) and ID2 as EmpID (Employee ID). so there will be multiple EmpID for 1 OrgID, if any of EmpID failed to meet salary criteria then OrgID should not be displayed.
To display OrgID, all EmpID should meet salary criteria.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's awesome man, I can't upvote your answer enough for the OP to see.

Comment: If condition is to print OrgID whose salary is equivaled to 1000 then having clause will fail.
@GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select OrgID, EmpID, name, salary FROM table_AGE 
WHERE OrgID not in
    (select OrgID from table_AGE where salary < 1000)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f3da9eceaaea616413f8e4ad80cddca

Comment: shouldn't it be like this `... INNER JOIN table_AGE t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1 ...`?

Comment: When i execute your query 
Select t2.id2 , t2.name, t2.salary from table_AGE t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2 
Where t2.salary > 1000

It's giving error
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 't2'.

Comment: Yes, I forget to put table name :  I edit my answer. Please try again

Comment: If any of ID2 does not meet salary criteria then ID1 value should not be printed. 
But in your query it's still printing.

ID1   ID2    Name   Salary 
1     1    Sam    800
1     2    Gel    1200
2     1    Moy    1100
1     3    Gar    1300


ID1 value 1 should not be displayed, even after (1     2    Gel    1200) (1     3    Gar    1300)  meets the salary criteria but (1     1    Sam    800) is not meeting salary criteria so ID1 1 should not be printed.

Comment: To clear your confusion, i updated column name in questions with ID1 as OrgID (which will be Organization ID) and ID2 as EmpID (Employee ID). so there will be multiple EmpID for 1 OrgID, if any of EmpID failed to meet salary criteria then OrgID should not be displayed.
To display OrgID, all EmpID should meet salary criteria.

Comment: Still not sure to understand: In your example only id2 = 2 should be print? As all id1= 2 has a salary > 1000

Comment: Please check question again, i have updated it now more readable.

|1    |1    |Sam |800   |
|1    |2    |Gel |1200  |
|1     |3    |Joy |2000  |

OrgID 1, has 3 EmpID out of 2 meets salary criteria so OrgID 1 should not be displayed.

But OrgID 2, has 2 EmpID and all meet salary criteria so OrgID 2 should be displayed.
|2    |1    |Moy |1100  |
|2    |2    |Gar |1300  |

Comment: @Adityasharma Check Gordon Linoff's aswer, it does what you want to do.

Comment: Ok I edit my answer again, hope to understand what you want ;)

Comment: @DonKnacki I want output OrgID 2 as output because it's all corresponds EmpID meets salary criteria

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c45e7e317b111c906bf6dad6600d0b41

Comment: @T0ny1234, as you said Gordon's answer is right but it's wrong. 
If any of EmpID correspondent to OrgID does not meet salary condition, then OrgID should not be printed.

OrgID has multiple EmpID, if all EmpID for same OrgID meets salary criteria then only it should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT id1
FROM table_AGE
WHERE salary > 1000;
```

This will print the `id1` for every record that has `salary > 1000`;

Comment: I want to print ID1 value only not ID2.

Comment: Remove the `id2` from the `SELECT` and you are good to go.

Comment: You can understand problem like There is OrganizationID column and EmployeeID column. For 1 OrgID there may be multiple EmpID so i just want to display those OrgID only whose EmpID meets the salary > 1000.

Example :

OrgID   EmpID    Name   Salary 
1     1    Sam    800
1     2    Gel    1200
2     1    Moy    1100
1     3    Gar    1300
3     1    Man    900
3     2    Joy    2000

So here only below line satisfy condition:
2     1    Moy    1100

Comment: I hope now you got my question. 
Because when if you say just remove ID2 from select and you are good to go. It will display ID1 for 1 as well but his ID2 value 1 does not met salary criteria so it should not print.

Comment: @Adityasharma why aren't `1 2 Gel 1200` and `1 3 Gar 1300` correct answers to your question? Why just `2 1 Moy 1100` is?

Comment: 1 2 Gel 1200  and 1 3 Gar 1300 will not qualify because 1     1    Sam    800 (ID2 of same ID1) failed to meet salary condition. 
Only those ID1 should be printed whose all ID2 meets the salary condition.

I hope now it's clear to you

Comment: To clear your confusion, i updated column name in questions with ID1 as OrgID (which will be Organization ID) and ID2 as EmpID (Employee ID). so there will be multiple EmpID for 1 OrgID, if any of EmpID failed to meet salary criteria then OrgID should not be displayed.
To display OrgID, all EmpID should meet salary criteria.